# Images aren't rendering on Git hub pages

Tags: image, github

I've tried everything. Pushed all image files to Git hub repo. They're all lowercase .jpg and everything appears fine locally in the editor.  Still not showing up on Git hub pages.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the image in same repository, for example .\doc\image.jpg
2. In *.md file (I assume you talking about readme.md or some other doc in md format) put link to the image like this:

```
![My Image](https://github.com/<github-user>/<repository>/blob/master/doc/image.jpg?raw=true)
```

The easy way to get the url - just navigate to uploaded image in web interface, right-click on the image and copy URL :-)